# new identity for TOR using perl on linux

Tags: perl, tor

I am running a perl script to read data for many different websites via the [TOR network](https://www.torproject.org). But some of this sites have blacklisted some TOR exit nodes and send the http-status 403 instead of the expected response. In this cases I want to send a command to my local TOR process to change its circuit/identity.

This leads me to my first (minor important) question:

> Do »**circuit**« and »**identity**« mean the same when talking about TOR?

But my more important question is this:

> How can I send a »*change identity*« command to a local running TOR process from a perl script?

(As far as I know by now this command is `signal newnym`, but how can I send it?)

[I asked this question already on TOR-StackExchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/control-tor-via-perl-script), and was told to execute the system call

```
pkill -SIGHUP tor
```

which should force TOR to reload its config files and then establish a new circuit, but this does not work. I guess it is because my socks-connection still is open and tor even after -SIGHUP keeps using the same identities for still open connections. (just guessing)

And I think it is some kind of overload to force TOR to reload its config files just for creating a new circuit. I think there must be a more elegant solution, like

1. create a connection to TOR's control port
2. send »change identity« (`signal newnym`)
3. close connection

How can this three steps be written in perl?

While reading some documentation I did read, that you have to enable the usage of the control port in some config file, and that you have to use a password. Please tell me how to do this all! - Thanx

Comment: The first question is probably better suited to the TOR community. I believe it will be very popular there. The actual Perl question with your algorithm described below might be very domain-specific and even a bit broad. I'm not going to close-vote as I think it's on-topic, but I'm also not very confident about a lot of help here. Best of luck. :)

Answer (score 4):

After crawling through manny different documentations I found a solution:

```
if (my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
            'PeerHost' => '127.0.0.1',
            'PeerPort' => '9051',
            'Proto'    => 'tcp')) {
    my @requ = ('authenticate ""','SIGNAL NEWNYM','QUIT');
    foreach my $requ (@requ) {
        print $socket $requ."\n";
        my $dummy = <$socket>;
    }
    $socket->close();
    print "OK: New circuit established\n";
} else {
    print "ERROR: couldn't connect with socket\n";
}
```

Explanation:

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
            'PeerHost' => '127.0.0.1',
            'PeerPort' => '9051',
            'Proto'    => 'tcp')
```

creates a new socket object. If this did work, it returns the socket, otherwise *undef*.

I embedded this statement in an *if*-Statement. Its first block will be executed if the socket could be created, the second block prints an error message.

In the *if*-Block, I send this three commants through the socket to TOR:

1. authenticate ""
2. SIGNAL NEWNYM
3. QUIT

1 performs the null-authentification
2 does what I really want: This command tells TOR to establish a new circuit.
3 quits the conversation

At the end I close the socket and print a message.

I don't analyze TOR's response, but I have to read it (with `$dummy = <$socket>;`). One could check, if TOR really answers three times with "250", and react if not. But I decided to hope, that it always works.

Comment: You picked the correct method, to do it programatically you have to open a connection to the control port and issue the `SIGNAL NEWNYM` command as you did.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not strictly need it to be Perl, a shell one-liner would do the trick, too:

Depending on your means of authentication (possibly a control_auth_cookie-file in data/tor), you could issue this one-liner (and by doing that also check that you got a new external ip, just to be sure), e.g.:

```
printf "AUTHENTICATE \"$(cat <<location of your control_auth_cookie file>>)\"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n" | nc localhost 9151; curl --socks5-host localhost:9150 http://myexternalip.com/raw
```

You will need to adjust `9151` to the actual service port number in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Just to re-iterate what Jinxed wrote, here are some easy to use copy/paste lines with one minor change: The Tor daemon will not close the session after you push the NEWNYM to it, so we put a -q1 to close the connection after 1 second of EOF. :)

`printf "AUTHENTICATE \"$(cat /usr/local/var/lib/tor/control_auth_cookie)\"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n" | nc localhost 9051 -q1; curl --socks5-host localhost:9050 http://myexternalip.com/raw`

For Port 9150/9150 configs:

`printf "AUTHENTICATE \"$(cat /usr/local/var/lib/tor/control_auth_cookie)\"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n" | nc localhost 9151 -q1; curl --socks5-host localhost:9150 http://myexternalip.com/raw`